# Gunicorn and Flask blueprints

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I'm using Gunicorn (on nginx) with Flask. Let's say I have two Python files, linked with a Flask Blueprint: `app.py` and `api.py` where `api.py` has the url prefix `/api`. **Why is it that any routes in `app.py` work although all Blueprinted (i.e. `/api`) routes return 404s?**

`app.py` looks something like this:

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '''cheese-bread'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.register_blueprint(api, url_prefix='/api')
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

and `api.py`

```
from flask import Blueprint, jsonify
api = Blueprint('/api', __name__)
@api.route('/')
def index():
    return jsonify({'bread' : 'cheese, please'})
```

`wsgi.py` is as simple as possible

```
from app import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run()
```

Startup scripts are not relevant as the 404s appear when running for development with `gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 wsgi:app`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you need to register the blueprint outside of `if __name__ == "__main__"`, since when you say `from app import app` it will not run any code in the guardblock

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '''cheese-bread'''
app.register_blueprint(api, url_prefix='/api')
if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

that way when you import it in wsgi it also has the blueprint registered ...

alternatively you could register the blueprint in the wsgi.py

Comment: feels like I was stuck on this problem is 2015. Thanks Joran!!